# Is there a way to make box-shadow go to the bottom of page?

Tags: html, css, shadow

I want to make the shadow of my image #afb1 to go to the bottom of the page without having blank page between the shadow and bottom of the page. Is this possible?

Like when I change #afb1 his height to 500px it gets taller, but I want it to connect to the bottom of the page

html:

```
<div id="pics">

        <div id="afb1">
            <img src="Images/Chingy.png" alt="mooiboy" height="200" width="200"                                onmouseover="this.src='Images/chingy.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/Chingy.png'">
        </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#pics{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width:880px;
height:100%;
}

#pics img{
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#afb1{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7fA78/

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous. Can you knock something up in paint?

Comment: Downvoter please comment first.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, for example if I change height from #afb1 to 500px; It has the correct size, but thats because of the content I have above it, I need to do it in % I think

Comment: **Not possible with pure CSS** as the box-shadow must be stated in absolute px values. You would need JS/JQ to calculate the distance from the element to the bottom of the page and apply that value to the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you only need the bottom of the image shadow  something like this

```
#afb1{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 10px 5px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

you need to adjust these settings box-shadow: **1px 10px 5px -1px** rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I mean more like this part "height:100%" I want it to go to to the bottom of the page, instead of only going down till the size from the image

Comment: and whether it will be seen?

Comment: 100% is the visible area of ​​the screen

Comment: Like when I change height to: 500px it will have the good size, but I need to do it with %

Comment: even as an option so you can try to insert another <div id="afb1"> div with 100% height and padding on the size of the shadow from the property box-size: border-box; nk and set shadow should get

Comment: and the page should be only one id is unique because it

Comment: also need to specify html body 100% margin: 0;, padding: 0;

Comment: I hope my tips will help you

Answer (score 1):

It *is* 100% of the page. The problem is your page is not 100% of the window. Add this

```
body,html{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
}
```